# Remove brackets and trailing whitespace from variable

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be a good regex for removing brackets and any (but only) trailing whitespace?

Example: `"Hello [world] - what is this?"` would translate to `"Hello - what is this?"`.

Comment: You mean bracketed words? Or anything that starts with `[` and ends with `]`. And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex. It will remove brackets and their trailing whitespaces.

```
/(\s\s)*(\s(?=\[.*?\]\s))*\[.*?\](\s\s)*/g
```

Usage:

```
var testStr = "Hello [world] - what is this?";
console.log(testStr.replace(/(\s\s)*(\s(?=\[.*?\]\s))*\[.*?\](\s\s)*/g, ""));
```

Inputs/Outputs:

```
Input: Hello [world] - what is this?            Output: Hello - what is this?
Input: Hello [world] - what  is  this?          Output: Hello - what  is  this?
Input: Hello [world] - what is     this?        Output: Hello - what is     this?
Input: Hello      [world] - what is this?       Output: Hello - what is this?
Input: Hello      [world]     - what is this?   Output: Hello - what is this?
Input: Hello [world]       - what is this?      Output: Hello - what is this?
Input: Hello [world]- what is this?             Output: Hello - what is this?
Input: Hello       [world]- what is this?       Output: Hello - what is this?
Input: Hello[world] - what is this?             Output: Hello - what is this?
Input: Hello[world]       - what is this?       Output: Hello - what is this?
Input: Hello[world]- what is this?              Output: Hello- what is this?
```

Comment: This is it - the others remove both leading and trailing white spaces around the brackets or leaves the spaces untouched - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can let the expression alternate between bracketed things and trailing white-space:

```
str.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]|\s+$/g, '')
```

The `/g` modifier is used to match all occurrences instead of only the first (default).

**Update**

In the case that `[hello]` is preceded by a space, that space will not get removed and you would need another `.replace()` instead of the alternation:

```
str.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/g, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
```

Comment: (+1) the most simple, the most optimized

Comment: I think he means trailing white space after the square brackets, not at the end of the string

Comment: @acdcjunior I'm assuming you meant that the space before the last bracketed expression is not removed? Yeah, just noticed it, and fixed.

Comment: @simonzack Well, it's somewhat open for interpretation I suppose :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var result = mystring.replace(/^\s*\[[^]]+]\s*|\s*\[[^]]+]\s*$|(\s)\s*\[[^]]+]\s*/g, '$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace(/\[.+?\]\s*/g,'');
```